# Property 'length' not found on object of type 'id'

Tags: iphone

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = [arrareasdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.designLabel.text = [arrareasdata1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(([arrareasdata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length > 0)  
    {
        cell.emailLabel.text = [arrareasdata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        cell.emailLabel.text = @"";
    }

    cell.webLabel.text = [arrareasdata3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please read the site's rules before you post.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here

```
if(([arrareasdata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length > 0)
```

what you must do is get object from the array and cast it into appropriate type. for example if the objects in array are `NSString` type then do following

```
NSString *value = (NSString*)[arrareasdata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

then in your if statement check for length

```
if (value.length > 0)
```